# Analyze data for spatial join (points to grid) and generate new dataset in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-grid

I've got a dataset with longitude/latitude points and an outcome value for each set of coordinates. I would like to create a spatial grid and then take the average of outcomes for coordinates that are in the same grid and generate a new dataframe for which each coordinate is assigned a grid number and has the averaged outcome. For example, starting with this code:

```
require(sp)
require(raster)

frame <- data.frame(x = c(7.5, 8.2, 8.3), y = c(1,4,4.5), z = c(10,15,30))

coordinates(frame) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(frame) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")

grid <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset= c(0,0), cellsize = c(2,2), cells.dim = c(5,5))
sg <- SpatialGrid(grid)
poly <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grid)
proj4string(poly) <-  CRS("+proj=longlat")

plot(poly)
text(coordinates(poly), labels = row.names(poly), col = "gray", cex. =.6)
points(frame$x, frame$y, col = "blue", cex = .8)
```

I would then like to average the outcomes (z) within grid cells and produce an dataframe that looks like this (.e.g. observation):

```
    x   y  z grid grid_mean
1 7.5 1.0 10   g20      10
2 8.2 4.0 15   g15     22.5
3 8.3 4.5 30   g15     22.5
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: The code you provided puts the first point on the boundary between g20 and g25, not in g10. Are you sure the grid is what you intend it to be? Plus, how do you want to deal with points on a boundary??

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've listed it at g20; for boundary points, random assignment would be my preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `over(...)` function in package `sp` for this. You don't need package `raster` at all, as far as I can see.

```
require(sp)

frame  <- data.frame(x = c(7.5, 8.2, 8.3), y = c(1,4,4.5), z = c(10,15,30))
points <- SpatialPoints(frame)
proj4string(points) <-  CRS("+proj=longlat")

grid  <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset= c(0,0), cellsize = c(2,2), cells.dim = c(5,5))
sg    <- SpatialGrid(grid)
poly  <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grid)
proj4string(poly) <-  CRS("+proj=longlat")

# identify grids...
result <- data.frame(frame,grid=over(points,poly))
# calculate means...
result <- merge(result,aggregate(z~grid,result,mean),by="grid")
# rename and reorder columns to make it look like your result
colnames(result) <- c("grid","x","y","z","grid_mean")
result <- result[,c(2,3,4,1,5)]
result
#     x   y  z grid grid_mean
# 1 8.2 4.0 15   15      22.5
# 2 8.3 4.5 30   15      22.5
# 3 7.5 1.0 10   25      10.0
```

The `over(x,y,...)` function compares two `Spatial*` objects as overlays and returns a vector with the index into `y` of each geometry in `x`. In this case `x` is a SpatialPoints object and `y` is a SpatialPolygons object. So `over(...)` identifies the polygon ID (grid cell) in `y` associated with each point in `x`. The rest just calculates the means, merges the means with the original data frame, and renames and reorders the columns so the result looks like your result.

I tweaked your code a bit because it didn't make sense: you create a data frame with z-values, then convert it to a SpatialPoints object, which discards the z-values...